# Python Regex for extracting specific part from string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
SOURCEFILE:  file_name.dc     : 1 : log: the logging area
```

I am trying to store anything inbetween the third and the fourth colon in a variable and discard the rest.

I've tried to make a regular expression to grab this but so far i have this which is wrong :

```
([^:]:[^:]*)
```

I would appreciate some help with this and an explanation of the valid regex so i can learn from my mistake.

Comment: What is the desired output exactly?

Comment: Why not use simply string.split(':')[3] ?

Comment: Please post the whole code to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Are colons (:) the only delimiting character? Or do you want a generic solution?

Comment: Sorry, @activatedgeek  i have edited my post. i need to store the removed text in a varaiable

Comment: @RitchieRamnial my question still stands! Can there be any other characters. If not, then you can simply split and access the indices.

Comment: @activatedgeek sorry, colons are the only delimiting character

Comment: @RitchieRamnial `map(lambda s: s.strip(), input.split(':'))[3]`, where `input` is your string. I also removed extra spaces. If you don't want that, then simply: `input.split(':')[3]`.

Comment: @activatedgeek That's it! thank you. if you make this into an answer i will make it the correct choice

Comment: @RitchieRamnial I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumptions have been made.

- The number of colons are always the same
- Colon (:) is always the delimiter.
- The input string is in the variable `input`

It is just a single line then:

```
result = map(lambda s: s.strip(), input.split(':'))[3]
```

If you need to preserve spaces:

```
result = input.split(':')[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "SOURCEFILE:  file_name.dc     : 1 : log: the logging area"
>>> s1 = re.sub(r"[^\:]*\:[^\:]*\:[^\:]*\:([^\:]*)\:.*", r"\1", s)
>>> print s1
log
```

Comment: I removed greedy operator .. now is it OK?

Comment: You do not have to escape `:`. It is not a special character in regex.

Comment: Yeah... I know but it is a good practice if you do that for any non-word character or any symbol.

Comment: Sorry, @MayurKoshti i have worded my question wrong  i need to discard everything but the text between the third and fourth colon

Comment: It is NOT a good practice to escape uselessly characters, that makes the regex unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "SOURCEFILE:  file_name.dc     : 1 : log: the logging area"
#find out all indices of colon in string
indices = [x.start() for x in re.finditer(":",s)]
result = s[:indices[2]] + s[indices[3]+1:] # remove 3rd and 4th colon as well
#result = s[:indices[2]+1] + s[indices[3]:] #remains 3rd and 4th colon
```

try to find out indices of 3rd and 4th colon, and concatenate the head and tail parts